# AWS SQS- If message fails to process, will transmission of message stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

If I have 5 messages in a batch, and 4th message fails during receive due to network failure. Will the message processing be blocked, 5th message will be processed or not for both standard and FIFO queues.

Answer (score 5):

In the FIFO case, when you receive a message with a message group ID, *no more messages* for the same message group ID are returned unless you delete the message or it becomes visible again (i.e. until you have successfully processed the first message with that group ID or you have proven to be unable to process it within the time allowed, in which case it becomes visible again at the head of the queue of messages with that group ID).

In the non-FIFO case, I would expect message processing to continue regardless.

For more, see [Amazon SQS FIFO (First-In-First-Out) Queues - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html).